# Need to urgently stop a data driven subscription from sending a multitude of emails

Tags: ssrs

can someone please help me so that I can have a job tomorrow.  Fairly new at this and I've searched and tried several suggestions on this site to no avail.  I made an error in my data driven script and now it's emailing me constantly.  It's only a matter of time before our security department comes down on me.  I can see the job ID but I don't see the subscription as running under SSMS Job Activity Monitor.  I've disabled the job under Subscriptions in SSRS.

How can I stop the emails?  It's sending batches every second.

I can turn off the MSSQLSERVER service and it temporarily stops, likewise I can set the IsSchedulingService in the rsreportserver.config file and it temporarily stops, but what is driving the constant emails?  I'm at a loss.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you "*made an error in my data driven [sub]script[ion]*" then why can't you go in and disable or delete it? You would do so the same place you managed it in the first place, in the SSRS instance's website. I'm confused on where you're stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Found an unorthodox fix and started to do it but it was taking a while and I didn't complete it so I won't post the 'suggestion solution' because it wasn't tested.  I ended up doing a restore.